# How to add time durations?

Tags: python, xml, datetime

I want to add time durations attributes in an xml file using Python 2.7.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import time

for k in root.findall('TC'):
    ttt= k.get('time')
    s = time.strptime(ttt, "%H:%M:%S")
    total_time = total_time + s
```

I can't use `+` operator, the error is `unsupported operand types (+) None_Type, time.struct_time`.

How can I define `total_time` as a `struct_time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert the `struct_time` components to a [`datetime.timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to sanely deal with time durations:

```
import datetime
import time

total_time = datetime.timedelta()
for k in root.findall('TC'):
    ttt= k.get('time')
    s = time.strptime(ttt, "%H:%M:%S")
    total_time = total_time + datetime.timedelta(
        hours=s.tm_hour, minutes=s.tm_minute, seconds=s.tm_second)
```

There is no easy way otherwise to convert the `struct_time` information to a duration; it is actually meant for date-time values, although using `.strptime()` to parse a duration is not too bad an idea.

Your `total_time` value is now a `datetime.timedelta()` object. To get the total number of seconds, use the [`.total_seconds()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) on it:

```
print total_time.total_seconds()
```